# Instantiate class using Type t as reflected

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following code. `t` is showing as invalid on the second line.

`Cannot resolve symbol 't'`

How can I instantiate a generic class using `Type t`.

```
Type t = currentProperty.PropertyType;
var x = new MyClass<t>();
```

thank you

Comment: That doesn't make sense; you don't have any compile-time type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are only a compile time feature, not a runtime feature. You need to create the class using reflection.

```
Type t = currentProperty.PropertyType;
Type desiredType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(t);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(desiredType);
```

Answer (score 2):

`t` is a type *object* computed at run-time; you can't use it in a place where the C# compiler is expecting a compile-time type *name*. The compiler is giving you that error because it can't find a type with the literal name "t".

But hark, you can still do what you want, albeit less simply:

```
var t = currentProperty.PropertyType;
var genericType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(t);
var x = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```